# Read only state in Redux

Tags: redux, state

In the Redux doc, it is clearly explain :
The only way to change the state is to emit an action.
In fact it's a very extremely good principle but nevertheless it seems to be possible to do that :

```js
const render = () => {
 document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "state : " + JSON.stringify(myStore.getState())
  myStore.getState().form.subobj.ssub.key2 = "ha ha";
};
```

[Full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/or3ux1rr/)

Why does not redux prevent external mutation ?
How can we ensure that developers will never do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code of `Redux` :

```
   var finalState = mapValues(finalReducers, (reducer, key) => {
      var previousStateForKey = state[key]
      var nextStateForKey = reducer(previousStateForKey, action)
      if (typeof nextStateForKey === 'undefined') {
        var errorMessage = getUndefinedStateErrorMessage(key, action)
        throw new Error(errorMessage)
      }
      hasChanged = hasChanged || nextStateForKey !== previousStateForKey
      return nextStateForKey
    })
```

`Redux` `combineReducers` treats state object as a plain JavaScript object

You have to use something like `immutablejs` along side with `redux` to achieve what you want.

Comment: So Redux does not protect itself against the direct mutations of the current state ?

Comment: It sadly can't because it is not part of the language (=JavaScript). This is why middleware like `redux-freeze` exist. The only why Redux could do it is by always giving you a deep copy of it's state, but the downside of this is that change detection gets bad. Meaning every time something in the state changes change detection would need to diff the whole state.

Answer (score 1):

Immutability of object is not job of Redux.

Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.

To work with immutable objects you could consider using `Immutable.js` or `dot-prop-immutable`.